# Copy/Pasting Data from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, I've been researching this for about 4 hours now.  I had another similar post that solved one problem only to create another.  This code grabs the same column of data from 2 spreadsheets.  The first copy/paste works great (and fills rows A2:A191), but the first loop after that pastes the data from that spreadsheet starting at row A1332??  All of the cells from A192:A1331 are blank.  The code should be looking for the first available empty cell looking from the bottom, up.  What am I missing?

Here's the code in question. I have verified that it unlocked the second loops spreadsheet range cells, but after that it pastes it wrong?  Formatting doesn't seem to be an issue?  Is there "something" that could be in the cell that I'm not seeing?

```
 Set wbkCS = Workbooks.Open(strCutSheetFile(i))
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set wbkVer = Workbooks.Open(strVerifyFile)
        Set copyRng = Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("A2")
    If copyRng = "" Then
            wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Locked = False
            wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy Destination:=wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("A2")
    Else
            wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Locked = False
            wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy Destination:=wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("A" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
     End If
```

Comment: check Chuff's answer. But also when you protect the spreadsheet if you add UserInterfaceOnly = true you will not need to lock/ unlock as the sheet is only locked down for users and not VBA automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try qualifying the last range reference in your second copy statement,i.e.:

Instead of

```
    .Range("A" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
```

Try

```
    .Range("A" & wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
```

Comment: you'll probably upgrade to the next version of Excel at some point so I'd not hard-code in `A65536` ...rather change code to `.Range("A"& wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)`